# EF can you make a Mutli-column Index using shadow properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to create a multi-column unique index using a shadow property. I know I can solve this problem with just adding a property, but I would like to see if this is possible in a way to keep my model clean.

To create a multi-column index you have the following option in Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>().HasIndex(t => new { t.TrackNumber, t.AlbumId).IsUnique();
```

But I don't want to clutter my model with an extra `AlbumId` property and thus would like to use a shadow property, for a single column this works as followed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>().HasIndex(t => EF.Property<int>(t,"AlbumId")).IsUnique();
```

I tried the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
    .HasIndex(t => new { t.TrackNumber, EF.Property<int>(t,"AlbumId")})
    .IsUnique();
```

However my IDE throws the following error:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Anybody has an idea how to do this with using a shadow properties or is this just not possible?

*edit: various grammar arrors.*

Comment: Unfortunately even if you define a name (`.HasIndex(t => new { t.TrackNumber, AlbumId = EF.Property<int>(t, "AlbumId") })` and avoid compilation error, you get runtime error *"The properties expression 't => new <>f__AnonymousType11`2(TrackNumber = t.TrackNumber, AlbumId = Property(t, "AlbumId"))' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression*". So the string overload from my answer is currently the only choice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible. You can simply use the `HasIndex` overload with `params string[] propertyNames`.

First make sure the shadow property is defined:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
    .Property<int>("AlbumId");
```

and then define the index:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
    .HasIndex("TrackNumber", "AlbumId")
    .IsUnique();
```

Comment: Yes, it was that simple, thank you very much. The property method is without the has, like .Property, but not that anybodies IDE wouldn't catch that, thank you.